# How to disable eslint parsing error for injected delimiter?

Tags: javascript, haml, eslint

I've been using haml for a decade. Now that I'm writing React, I'm getting an eslint parsing error for the haml delimiter. I may get additional errors on this in the future, but for now I've only seen the following. Please help me disable the rule for this case. Thank you.

`Parsing error, unexpected token, epected "," (Fatal)`

for working code that reloads just fine...

#### both samples work

```
return (~
    <h2>hi</h2>
  ~)
```

#### and

```
return (
  (~ <h2>hi</h2> ~)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eslint does not support haml and as far as I know there is no plugin to add a support. Did you consider moving your hamls to separate files, which will not be targeted by eslint and lint them with [haml-lint](https://github.com/brigade/haml-lint) or any other similar util?

Comment: i ought to do that. Thanks.